# How to write on already open excel sheet in Selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium

I have 2 excel sheets. Current my requirement is, I need to perform some action on excel column values and write that value in one of above mentioned excel sheets. Below I mentioned the my code but it throws error at row3 line.

```
File file=new File("D:\\Udaya files\\D-udaya files\\desktop_udaya files\\markting\\Gartner Dashboard\\Gartner Dashboard 28-12-2018\\AdminReportHTCoverPage.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(1);
        XSSFRow row=null;
        int rowcount=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;

        File dashboard=new File("D:\\Udaya files\\D-udaya files\\desktop_udaya files\\markting\\Gartner Dashboard\\Gartner Dashboard 28-12-2018\\Weekly Dashboard_Garner users FY 18.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb1=new XSSFWorkbook(dashboard);
        XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheet("December 28th");
        XSSFRow row1=null;
        int dashcount=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
        int free=0;
        int paid=0;
        int paid_count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<dashcount;i++)
        {
            String name=sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            for(int j=0;j<rowcount;j++)
            {
                String firstname=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                if(name.equals(firstname))
                {
                    if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).getStringCellValue()== "0" || sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).getStringCellValue()== "")
                    {
                        free=free+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     int value= (int) sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
                     paid=paid+value;
                     paid_count=paid_count+1;
                    }               
                }
                Row row3=sheet1.getRow(i);
                row3.getCell(2).setCellValue(free);
                row3.getCell(3).setCellValue(paid_count);
                row3.getCell(4).setCellValue(paid);
            }

        }
```

getLastRowNum() not working properly for sheet1 file. It not displaying the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

`XSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()` is zero-based. 
This is why you think that it does not represent the correct number if you get `row number - 1` as a result.

If row number is `5` in the Excel Sheet, `XSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()` will return 4.

You can also find good examples in the link below;
http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

What kind of error you get in your code?

Comment: Thank you. But I have 34 rows in excel sheet, it returns total number of rows as 19. I'm getting the "Null Pointer Exception"  at  Row row3=sheet1.getRow(i);